# UDP in C++ in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, udp

How to send and receive, using UDP, in C++ in Linux?
I use g++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it's preety simple. I was workig in CentOS 5.5 which is linux and i make a server-client programme based on **udp** in c.It runs well.

The procedure is simple.
It follows as ..

```
**SERVER**

0.Variable initialization
1.sock()
2.bind()
3.recvfrom()
4.sendto()

**CLIENT**

0.gethostbyname()
1.sock()
2.bzero()
4.sendto()
5.recvfrom()
```

You will understand the code if you see the documentation.

If its not work that way then go to >> matrixsust.blogspot.com for source.

Answer (score 3):

Using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime4.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Berkeley Sockets API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).